Filter DataFrame events not in time windows DataFrame
I have a DataFrame of events (Event Name - Time) and a DataFrame of time windows (Start Time - End Time).
I want to get a DataFrame containing only the events not in any of the time windows.
I am looking for a "pythonic" way to filter the DataFrame.
Example:
Events DataFrame:



Event Name
Event Time




Event1
02/01/2000 00:00:00


Event2
05/01/2000 10:00:00


Event3
07/01/2000 09:00:00


Event4
10/01/2000 02:00:00



Time Windows DataFrame:



Time Window Name
Start Time
End Time




Window1
01/01/2000 00:00:00
06/01/2000 00:00:00


Window2
10/01/2000 01:00:00
10/01/2000 04:00:00



Result:
Filtered Events DataFrame:



Event Name
Event Time




Event3
07/01/2000 09:00:00



Setup:
import pandas as pd

events_data = {
    'Event Name': ['Event1', 'Event2', 'Event3', 'Event4'],
    'Event Time': ['02/01/2000 00:00:00', '05/01/2000 10:00:00', '07/01/2000 09:00:00', '10/01/2000 02:00:00']
}

time_windows_data = {
    'Time Window Name': ['Window1', 'Window2'],
    'Start Time': ['01/01/2000 00:00:00', '10/01/2000 01:00:00'],
    'End Time': ['06/01/2000 00:00:00', '10/01/2000 04:00:00']
}

events_df = pd.DataFrame(events_data)
time_windows_df = pd.DataFrame(time_windows_data)

events_df['Event Time'] = pd.to_datetime(events_df['Event Time'], format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
time_windows_df['Start Time'] = pd.to_datetime(time_windows_df['Start Time'], format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
time_windows_df['End Time'] = pd.to_datetime(time_windows_df['End Time'], format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')


You can build an IntervalIndex then create a boolean mask with reindex:
# build IntervalIndex
idx = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df_time['Start Time'], df_time['End Time'])

# build boolean mask
m = (pd.Series(False, index=idx)
       .reindex(df_events['Event Time'],fill_value=True)
       .to_numpy()
    )

# select non-matching rows
out = df_events[m]

Alternative to build m:
m = idx.reindex(df_events['Event Time'])[1] == -1

Output:
  Event Name          Event Time
2     Event3 2000-01-07 09:00:00

Intermediates:
# idx
IntervalIndex([(2000-01-01 00:00:00, 2000-01-06 00:00:00],
               (2000-01-10 01:00:00, 2000-01-10 04:00:00]],
              dtype='interval[datetime64[ns], right]')

# m
array([False, False,  True, False])

Reproducible inputs:
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Timestamp

df_events = pd.DataFrame({'Event Name': ['Event1', 'Event2', 'Event3', 'Event4'],
                          'Event Time': [Timestamp('2000-01-02 00:00:00'),
                                         Timestamp('2000-01-05 10:00:00'),
                                         Timestamp('2000-01-07 09:00:00'),
                                         Timestamp('2000-01-10 02:00:00')]})
df_time = pd.DataFrame({'Time Window Name': ['Window1', 'Window2'],
                        'Start Time': [Timestamp('2000-01-01 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2000-01-10 01:00:00')],
                        'End Time': [Timestamp('2000-01-06 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2000-01-10 04:00:00')]})


I am getting  unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray' on out = events_data[m]

@YakirShlezinger can you provide your inputs in a reproducible format?

@Yakir check the update for a reproducible input, also please if this doesn't work for you please provide your pandas version

I edited the post, anyway, I tried again and it seems to work (maybe I misspelled something in the first time)

That is a really creative solution!

You can use this approach:
inside_events_df = events_df.merge(time_windows_df, how="cross")
inside_events_df[["Event Time", "Start Time", "End Time"]] = inside_events_df[
    ["Event Time", "Start Time", "End Time"]
].apply(pd.to_datetime)
inside_events_df = inside_events_df[
    (inside_events_df["Event Time"] > inside_events_df["Start Time"])
    & (inside_events_df["Event Time"] < inside_events_df["End Time"])
]

events_df = events_df[~events_df["Event Name"].isin(inside_events_df["Event Name"])]

  Event Name           Event Time
2     Event3  07/01/2000 09:00:00


I like this approach but it uses a lot of memory (with large DataFrames) because of the cross operation

You can get a concise solution with piso
import piso
piso.register_accessors()

result = (
    pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(
        time_windows_df['Start Time'],
        time_windows_df['End Time'],
    )
    .piso.complement()
    .piso.contains(events_df.set_index('Event Name')['Event Time'], result="points")
    .pipe(lambda x: x[x]).index
)

Disclaimer: I am the author of piso
